# Sending IOS Push Notifications from Ruby On Rails

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I need to send push notifications to IOS mobile.

I used apn_on_rails for send this notifications.

I get my pem file from IOS developer.
I did  the following configurations on it

In Productions & development in config/configtran/*.rb

```
RAILS_ROOT, APN::App::RAILS_ENV='production'
configatron.apn.passphrase  = 'leo_123'
configatron.apn.port  = 2195
configatron.apn.host  = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com'
configatron.apn.cert = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', ' apple_push_notification_development.pem')
```

And then i created one Notificationby following the documentation.

After i ran the following commands it stands ideal and responding

From console

APN::App.send_notifications

Using rake
       RAILS_ENV=production rake apn:notifications:deliver

I tried that in both production and development environment.
 After the follwing line it's not responding. I didn't found anything in Log also.

```
APN::App Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "apn_apps".* FROM "apn_apps"
```

I haven't hosted this app in any cloud server. Is this application should host in any cloud server to work the app properly?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You should create notification:
https://github.com/PRX/apn_on_rails#example-assuming-you-have-created-an-app-and-stored-your-keys-on-it

Comment: i already created the notification

Comment: I think in `apn_on_rails` you need to run migration. It uses db tables. If you don't want any table, you can use grocer gem.

Comment: i ran migrations on production for apn_on _rails. Let me check that grocer gem also

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easier to work with [grocer](https://github.com/grocer/grocer) gem.

```
pusher = Grocer.pusher(certificate: "#{Rails.root}/lib/dev_cert.pem", # required
                       passphrase:  "XXXXXX",                         # optional
                       gateway:     "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com", # optional
                       port:        2195,                             #optional
                       retries:     3)

feedback = Grocer.feedback( certificate: "#{Rails.root}/lib/dev_cert.pem", 
                                  passphrase:  "XXXXXX",                        
                                  gateway:     "feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com", 
                                  port:        2196,                     
                                  retries:     3)

 notification = Grocer::Notification.new(
    device_token:      push_id,
    alert:             message,
    badge:             3,
    sound:             "siren.aiff",         # optional
    expiry:            Time.now + 60*60,     # optional; 0 is default, meaning the message is not stored
    # identifier:        1234,                 # optional
    content_available: true                  # optional; any truthy value will set 'content-available' to 1
  )

  feedback.each do |attempt|
    puts "Device #{attempt.device_token} failed at #{attempt.timestamp}"
  end

  pusher.push(notification)
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55369/discussion-between-user2503775-and-santosh).

Comment: Let u please send the notification again

Comment: HI please send the notification and please Fork my code and merge your code, my messages are not going

Comment: lol iam working since two days,i need ur help, please share the code

Comment: It's returning with numbers but i didn't get any notifications in device. can u please send one notification from ur side

Comment: Please post your changed  code here or any gist otherwise fork my app and send merge request

Comment: To your prev pem file?

Comment: NO the pem file that you shared to me

Comment: Can you please try with my latest commit file is lib/test.pem

Comment: yes, that is the same but it's not working in my side, i just copy paste that

Comment: please push the code to your github send me link in chat

Comment: I sent 2 PN in the past hour.

Comment: what's message "test PN" only Or u sent any  "Hello from Santosh" message

Comment: I think only "test PN"

Comment: ok please push ur code to github and send a link or fork my project